# ORDER BY WHERE IN(subquery)

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT products.* FROM products
WHERE products.code = 'search word' OR products.id IN(SELECT product_names.product_id 
                     FROM product_names 
                     WHERE MATCH (product_names.name) 
                     AGAINST ('+search* +word*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                     ORDER BY product_names.sorting_field)
ORDER BY ???
```

I want the order of the main query be the same as the order with the `WHERE IN()`. I can't seem to use `FIELD` or `FIND_IN_SET` because I don't know what I am getting back from the `MATCH AGAINST`.

I tried things like `ORDER BY FIELD(products.id, product_names.product_id)` etc. but I didn't figure out how to make it work.

In reality my query is a lot longer and more complicated, this is a somewhat pseudo version of it. I can't do the `MATCH AGAINST` outside the subquery.

Comment: Why can't you "*do the `MATCH AGAINST` outside the subquery*"?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   products.*
FROM     products LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, sorting_field
  FROM   product_names 
  WHERE  MATCH (product_names.name) AGAINST ('+search* +word*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
) t ON products.id = t.product_id
WHERE    products.code = 'search word' OR t.product_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.sorting_field
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked beautifully in a sense. The down side was that the query takes a huge time to load since the match against is done once per product where as on the first query it's only done once.

Comment: Would mysql variables help me with my query?

Comment: @unska: I'm not sure that I understand.  The `MATCH ... AGAINST ...` is evaluated exactly once for each record in `product_names` (as it was in your original query).  If you have performance problems, please post as a new question showing the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>` together with the query itself and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table referenced.